# Program does not initially draw correctly

Tags: windows-7, compatibility, graphics

We just got a new i3 Win7 64 desktop with an Intel GMA HD to replace an aged machine. When I launch one old software program (written for win95), the program starts with the window outline, but does not draw most of its screen. If I resize the program, it displays properly. If I click on parts of the program, those parts display properly. If I launch, close, launch again it usually displays properly.

The program runs fine on an XP desktop and a Win7 notebook.

The new desktop has the latest drivers. I've tried various compatibility modes, without success.

I tried writing a simple script to launch the program and resize its window, but that does not work all of the time.

Any suggestions for fixing this?

Answer (score 1):

In the compatibility options, set the option `Disable visual themes` and `Disable desktop composition`. Does this improve it?

http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7/make-older-programs-run-in-this-version-of-windows

Comment: That may work. One problem is that it changes Windows color scheme to Basic, not just for the problem program but for all programs, and that the screen flashes when launching the program. I suppose I could just change to Basic for everything.

Comment: if you have Win7 Enterprise, Prof or Ultimate install the XPMode and use the old software there.

Comment: Isn't XPMode essentially a virtual PC? If so, that would seem more disruptive than a screen flash or temporary change to Basic mode or just resizing the problem program's window.

Comment: yes, this is a VM, but it has the purpose to run old legacy programs which have issues with Win7. And it integrated very well into windows 7 (seamless integration, no extra Window, only a small green border to show that this tool runs in XPMode)